# Evil Org-Mode set L and H to tabbar movements

Tags: org-mode, evil

I can toggle org-mode TODO status with L and H when the pointer rests at a org heading. I wish I could bind those keys to tabbar-"movements" to mimic the behaviour I get in all othem mode with this simple snippet while the pointer is not above an org heading.

```
  (define-key evil-normal-state-map "L" 'tabbar-forward-tab)
  (define-key evil-normal-state-map "H" 'tabbar-backward-tab)
```

When I hit L or H I get this currently:

```
user-error: To use shift-selection with Org mode, customize ‘org-support-shift-select’
```

How can I customize the org-support-shift-select so I get the behaviour I want?

Answer (score 0):

From `org-support-shift-select`'s docstring:

> Non-nil means make shift-cursor commands select text when possible.

You have to set it to `t` by adding this to your configuration:

```
(setq org-support-shift-select t)
```